# How to merge struct column to one data type column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column of a values containing floats, integers and strings (numbers) e.g. 10, 10.1, "10".
The problem I'm experiencing with bigquery is that I can't seem to find a way to convert all the values to the same data type e.g float, without creating new columns.

`

```
select amount from `transactions`
```

`Output: returns the amount column like this:`|amount.integer|amount.float|amount.string|amount.provided|`

Desired output:
amount

I tried to cast the column as a float and int but kept getting an error.

`

```
select cast(amount as float64) from `transactions`


Invalid cast from STRUCT<float FLOAT64, integer INT64, string STRING, ...> to FLOAT64 at [1:13]
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to solve my question using the **[coalesce](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#coalesce)** function like below.

```
select cast(coalesce(amount.integer, amount.float, cast (amount.string as float64))) from `transactions`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, solved in this way:

```
SELECT cast(coalesce(amount.integer, amount.float) as float64)
FROM transactions
```

coalesce to retrieve the value and then cast to float